# CSS calc Invalid Property Value on Chrome. CSS file contains space. but it's not working on browser. how to fix it?

Tags: css

min.css file (cal contains space)

```
.img_slide_button_wrap{position:absolute;top:calc(50% - 32px);left:cal(50% + 8px);
```

on Chrome (cal doesn't contain space. why?)

```
 .img_slide_button_wrap{position:absolute;top:calc(50% - 32px);left:cal(50%+8px);
```

[image]

It should be applied like a css file. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

There’s a typo. It’s `calc`, not `cal`.